# How to embed facebook (like button and like box) in an esternal flash page

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript, embed

I am creating my new website, I have a Facebook page and I would like to embed the facebook's like button and the facebook's like box directly in my actionscript... Is it possible?

In the case it is not possible, could I embed them in the html in a way I can see them over the swf?

Thank You Very Much,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.

Alessandro,.. why are you making a website in flash?

ipads can't see it, iphone can't see it, and Android can't see it (unles you have firefox with custom installed flash player)

why don't you do it in html,css,jquery ??

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alvaro...

And ... you are right... To be honest I did not know Flash had so many problems with iOs and Android... Seems I will have to come back to html...

Comment: Flash is great for animations and FX, but you can do a pretty nice website with html + css + jquery, jquery allows you to animate also. Of course there is HTML5 and all that.. but I don't use html5, because not all browsers support it.